# react-scripts with service worker cannot see static files after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, react-scripts

My web app with react-scripts v.1.0.17 after adding service-workers responses with 200 but cannot see any static files prefixed with %PUBLIC_URL% in public folder like following image:

[image]

Folder structure in project:

[image]
and files paths in index.html are like:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
```

after build
and like:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
```

in my code.

My homepage in package.json file is declared as

```
"homepage": ".",
```

I got also default registerServiceWorker.js file in src folder.

Did I miss some important file or should I cache all this files manually ?